# How to (not) specify scope in class libraries with Ninject3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I've an ASP.NET MVC application using Ninject3 (NuGet install). The solution contains:

- an MVC project (**composition root**);
- a Domain Model project;
- a Data Layer project;
- a scheduler project (running scheduled jobs within a windows service and holding an alternative **composition root**);
- some other projects.

I'm following the approach to have many small modules spread across the projects defining the bindings. The two composition roots use exactly the same bindings.

I cannot figure out how to configure scope for the modules within the class libraries. For example, given these bindings:

```
Bind<IDomainService1>()
  .To<Service1Impl>()
  .InSingletonScope(); //This should always be a singleton

Bind<IDomainService2>()
  .To<Service2Impl>(); //No scope specified
```

I would always want a single instance of `Service1Impl`, whereas scope for `Service2Impl` should depend on the composition root used. MVC project should have `InRequestScope()` for `Service2Impl` (and for all other bindings with unspecified scope). Scheduler project, which does not run within an http context, should use `InThreadScope()`.

Is this approach correct? If yes, what is the right way of configuring this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In Ninject, not specifying the scope means `InTransientScope()`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

Your choices are to either duplicate the bindings or create a custom `InScope()` scoping rule for the binding.

The cleanest solution (especially given that MVC is already in play) is for you to create a plugin that slots into the `InRequestScope()` mechanism.

There is a `CreateScope()` method which currently has minimal documentation in the ninject.extensions.namedscope README, which is used [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15836383/11635). It requires you to select 'Include Prerelease' in NuGet. (And I should be writing a wiki article on it but I have too many other things on my plate...)