# Ninject Factory + InCallScope + ContextPreservation

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

First of all, I'm aware of the related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769209/ninject-factory-extension-and-incallscope-does-not-give-expected-results), but that post is quite old, and what's more important, not answered straightly.

So now I use the latest Ninject (stable, 3.2 Nuget packages) and the above mentioned extensions, and still see a non-expected behavior.

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Foo {}

public class Parent {
  public IFoo foo;
  public IFoo foo2;
  public Func<IFoo> fooFactory;
  public Parent(IFoo foo, Func<IFoo> factory) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.fooFactory = factory;
  }
  public void init() { this.foo2 = this.fooFactory(); }
}

...

kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InCallScope();
var instance = kernel.Get<Parent>();
instance.init();
instance.foo.ShouldEqual(instance.foo2);
```

This test fails, so it seems like the context is not preserved for the factory function, and it creates a new `Foo`.

How to achieve the expected behavior?

**UPDATE**

Based on a comment I've tried the same code with a declared `IFooFactory` interface bound with `ToFactory()`. The behavior is the same though.

**UPDATE 2**

I've just tried with the latest unstable factory and context preservation extensions, and the result is still the same.

Comment: Did you try to use [Factory interface](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface) instead of [Func](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Func)?

Comment: Not yet, I prefer using the delegates if there is no other logic beyond that. I'm gonna try it now.

Comment: The note by author might indicate you worth a try. Quote: _Even if it takes no arguments I personally think factory interfaces are a cleaner way to manage factories; while you do have to write a little more code, the improved readability vs a Func<T> is worth the effort_

Comment: Actually it's not working with `IFooFactory` either. Anyway, readability is sometimes subjective, if I read `Func<T>` I immediately know there are no parameters. Only thing I see an advantage of explicitly declared interfaces   in this particular case is a bit more flexible extensibility.

Comment: can you please verify that injecting two `IFoo` instances gives the same result? Just to check that the ContextPreservationExtension is installed correctly. I guess it's best to extend the test to inject two `IFoo`s into constructor and create one by factory.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Injecting two `IFoo` instances won't test context preservation, or am I wrong? It would test only `InCallScope` behavior. It's the factory that would test context preservation.

Comment: @Zoltan, oh yeah of course, you're right...

Comment: I've also checked if the context preservation module was loaded, and yes it was. Any idea please?

Comment: ... This is still an active question. The context preservation module's GitHub repository seems to be dead, as I've posted this issues there and still haven't received any kind of reactions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 calls. One is `kernel.Get<Parent>()`, the other is `instance.init()`.